# How can I create a share on my Windows 11 running in a HyperV VM?

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v

I have created a new HyperV VM running Windows 11 Pro. I want to share a folder on this system that I can access on my network using \server\share.

I have tried everything I know but I can't get the \server to be visible on the network. What steps do I need to take, in HyperV and/or Windows to make it accessible?

And is there anything I need to do other than sharing the folder for the share to be accessible?

**Details:**

Opening the VM using Connect in Hyper-V, in the VM I can open a browser and connect to websites. So it has a network connection out to the world.

The virtual switch defined in Hyper-V is:
[image: virtual switch definition]

The VM is named Jessica and the host system is named Jasmine. From Jessica it can ping itself and the host system:
[image: ping from jessica]

But from the host system, while it has the correct IP address, it can't ping it:
[image: ping from jasmine]

And trying "net view \jessica" from the host system (also Windows 11 Pro) gets me "System error 1707 has occurred. The network address is invalid."

Comment: You create a shared folder on a virtual machine just like you do on a physical machine. There isn't anything special regarding it being a virtual machine. What kind of virtual switch is the VM connected to? Does the VM have a valid ip address configuration for your network?

Comment: @joeqwerty I added a lot more info. Does this help? TIA

Comment: Try connecting/browsing to the virtual host or the share by name directly. Network discovery is not reliable.

Comment: @DanielB - Tried "net view \\jessica", no luck